# dot dot dot JS plugin dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to use dotdotdot JS plugin on my Django site, but it doesnt work for me. why? I just want to element to have dotdotdot on the end
This is HTML head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/static/mainpage/dotdotdot-1.6.5/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#prispevek").dotdotdot({
            /*  The HTML to add as ellipsis. */
            ellipsis    : '... ',

            /*  How to cut off the text/html: 'word'/'letter'/'children' */
            wrap        : 'word',

            /*  Wrap-option fallback to 'letter' for long words */
            fallbackToLetter: true,

            /*  jQuery-selector for the element to keep and put after the ellipsis. */
            after       : null,

            /*  Whether to update the ellipsis: true/'window' */
            watch       : false,

            /*  Optionally set a max-height, if null, the height will be measured. */
            height      : null,

            /*  Deviation for the height-option. */
            tolerance   : 10,

            /*  Callback function that is fired after the ellipsis is added,
                receives two parameters: isTruncated(boolean), orgContent(string). */
            callback    : function( isTruncated, orgContent ) {},

            lastCharacter   : {

                /*  Remove these characters from the end of the truncated text. */
                remove      : [ ' ', ',', ';', '.', '!', '?' ],

                /*  Don't add an ellipsis if this array contains 
                    the last character of the truncated text. */
                noEllipsis  : []
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is css:

```
#prispevek

{
    height:80px;
    /*text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;*/
    text-align: justify;
}
```

this is my body: Content is through Django

```
{% for object in prispevky %}
    <article>
        <h1><a href="novinky/{{ object.id }}/">{{ object.nadpis }}</a></h1>
        <p id="prispevek">{{ object.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you've got more than one `prispevky` object, you'll have more than one `id="prispevek"`, which is invalid HTML. You should use `id="prispevek"` and `$(".prispevek")` in your jQuery.

Comment: you should use class="prispevek" not id.

Comment: @DanielRoseman your comment is wrong.  user2771714 for `text-overflow:ellipsis` to work you also need to have `white-space:nowrap`.  does your dot plugin work on the first `prispevek` element or none of them?

Comment: Sorry guys, cut and paste error, I obviously did mean `class`.

Comment: This plugin doesnt work on any of them

Comment: does your console show any errors? (press f12 in your browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Id to class as id is unique and you are appending it inside a loop.

```
{% for object in prispevky %}
    <article>
        <h1><a href="novinky/{{ object.id }}/">{{ object.nadpis }}</a></h1>
        <p class="prispevek">{{ object.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Css

```
.prispevek

{
    height:80px;
    /*text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;*/
    text-align: justify;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".prispevek").dotdotdot({
```

Comment: still doesnt work. The text is overleaping (the text is on another text)